# Why am I getting Value cannot be null error in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Recently setup a new server.
I have been transferring everything over from our previous Sharepoint.

Anyway, we ran into an issue where when you try to edit some of the items in a list we get an error with a correlation ID, and some you can edit without a problem.

I have compared a broken item to a working item, I have exported to excel to compare them also. Everything is how it should be in the broken one, but yet it is still broken. You can delete a broken item and add a new one with the exact same info and it works fine.

This is the only thing I can make sense of in the SP logs.

---

Application error when access /my/companyweb/commercial/Lists/Passport 20 Tracking/EditForm.aspx, Error=Value cannot be null.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.GetProviderName(String fullName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.IsEncodedClaim(String value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PickerEntity.get_Claim()

---

What is the provider name? Is that the problem? I don't know....

---

EDIT
I have removed all columns that were using a lookup. 
The only thing other than basic data is a calculated field.

=TEXT([Sent to GE],"mmm") And that should not be the issue.

---

Comment: looks all good to me, i don't see any problems here, the safest way to determine the problem will be using the SharePoint ULS Logs which you were tracking and I still believe you need to get more rows for ULS for comprehensive analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to help you is having more information, please share what the list is suppose to look like in the sense of describing the columns, the types, the validation formulas, if they have also calculated columns, and if the list has indexes, lookup columns, and if there are workflows associated to the list.

Mostly common cases are associated to broken lookups, columns validations, and workflows, you think everything is working because you migrated the workflows associated to the list but the columns internally use their own IDs, the same happens to lookups, and column validations and/or calculated fields usually might be using PHYSICAL COLUMN NAMES instead of their logical names, check the items above, you might discover something.

Comment: Edited my post with info about data